# A small riddle, easy but distant

Tags: riddle

Runt of the litter, I was cast from the family.
They called me cold and distant but I do have a heart.
Many fear me although I have brought laughter and wealth.
You do not want to be where I dwell...
And yet you are already in me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are

> Pluto.

Runt of the litter, I was cast from the family.

> Pluto was the smallest planet until deemed not a planet in 2006.

They called me cold and distant but I do have a heart.

> It's far from the sun and has a cold temperature. Pluto's internal structure is theorised to consist of a silicate core surrounded by a water ice mantle.

Many fear me although I have brought laughter and wealth.

> Pluto was the Roman god of the underworld, and people fear death. Pluto the comical Disney character is a source of laughter. The Greek word *ploutos*, which appears in English words such as "plutocracy", means wealth.

You do not want to be where I dwell...

> Pluto lives in the underworld, and people generally aren't all that excited to leave the world of the living.

And yet you are already in me.

> You in text-speak is U, which is one letter in "Pluto".

Comment: Yep! I believe you were first by a minute.

Comment: @Amoz Not even a full minute.

Comment: The last one really stretches my grammatical understanding of english

Answer (score 10):

I think you are

> PLUTO.

Runt of the litter, I was cast from the family.

> Formerly the smallest planet in our solar system. Now no longer even classified as a planet.

They called me cold and distant but I do have a heart.

> Cold and distant for sure. As for the heart, see e.g. [this photo](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-s-new-horizons-a-heart-from-pluto-as-flyby-begins).

Many fear me although I have brought laughter and wealth.

> Not sure about the fear, but maybe it's a reference to PLUTOnium which is highly radioactive, used in nuclear weapons, and one of the most poisonous substances known to man. Laughter perhaps because of the Walt Disney character. Wealth because of PLUTOCRACY and the like, though originally Pluto (god of the underworld) and Ploutos (god of wealth) were two separate gods.

You do not want to be where I dwell...

> The far reaches of the solar system. Pretty chilly there, and not much atmosphere.

And yet you are already in me.

> Well, at any rate (the letter) U is.